# Javascript page doesn't display database values

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to display all the databases and tables of each databases in tree format. So I have written a code Jsp page in my code fetches the database names and table names and pass it to a javascript page. But in my code Javascript page displayes one database name only. Can anyone help me to find out the reason? My code:

LeftFrameset.jsp

```
 <%-- 
Document   : LeftFrameset
Created on : Nov 13, 2014, 1:10:22 PM
Author     : user
--%>
   <%@page import="querywork.DBConnection"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.DatabaseMetaData"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>

<!--------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-- Copyright (c) 2006 by Conor O'Mahony.                     -->
<!-- For enquiries, please email GubuSoft@GubuSoft.com.        -->
<!-- Please keep all copyright notices below.                  -->
<!-- Original author of TreeView script is Marcelino Martins.  -->
<!--------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-- This document includes the TreeView script.  The TreeView -->
<!-- script can be found at http://www.TreeView.net.  The      -->
<!-- script is Copyright (c) 2006 by Conor O'Mahony.           -->
<!--------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-- Instructions:                                             -->
<!--   - Through the <STYLE> tag you can change the colors and -->
<!--     types of fonts to the particular needs of your site.  -->
<!--   - A predefined block with black background has been     -->
<!--     made for stylish people :-)                           -->
<!--------------------------------------------------------------->

<HEAD>

    <!-- This is the <STYLE> block for the default styles.  If   -->
    <!-- you want the black background, remove this <STYLE>      -->
    <!-- block.                                                  -->
    <STYLE>
        BODY {
            background-color: white;}
        TD {
            font-size: 10pt; 
            font-family: verdana,helvetica; 
            text-decoration: none;
            white-space:nowrap;}
        A {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;}
        .specialClass {
            font-family:garamond; 
            font-size:12pt;
            color:green;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-decoration:underline}
        </STYLE>

        <!-- If you want the black background, replace the contents  -->
        <!-- of the <STYLE> tag above with the following...
          BODY {
            background-color: black;}
          TD {
            font-size: 10pt; 
            font-family: verdana,helvetica; 
            text-decoration: none;
            white-space:nowrap;}
          A {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;}
        <!-- This is the end of the <STYLE> contents.                -->

        <!-- Code for browser detection. DO NOT REMOVE.              -->
        <SCRIPT src="ua.js"></SCRIPT>

        <!-- Infrastructure code for the TreeView. DO NOT REMOVE.    -->
        <SCRIPT src="ftiens4.js"></SCRIPT>

        <!-- Scripts that define the tree. DO NOT REMOVE.           
        <SCRIPT src="demoFramesetNodes.js"></SCRIPT> -->

    </HEAD>

    <BODY topmargin="16" marginheight="16">

        <!------------------------------------------------------------->
        <!-- IMPORTANT NOTICE:                                       -->
        <!-- Removing the following link will prevent this script    -->
        <!-- from working.  Unless you purchase the registered       -->
        <!-- version of TreeView, you must include this link.        -->
        <!-- If you make any unauthorized changes to the following   -->
        <!-- code, you will violate the user agreement.  If you want -->
        <!-- to remove the link, see the online FAQ for instructions -->
        <!-- on how to obtain a version without the link.            -->
        <!------------------------------------------------------------->
        <DIV style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"><TABLE border=0><TR><TD><FONT  size=-2><A style="font-size:7pt;text-decoration:none;color:silver" href="http://www.treemenu.net/" target=_blank>Javascript Tree Menu</A></FONT></TD></TR> </TABLE></DIV>

            <%

        try {
            String responseText = "";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", "root", "");

            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();

            ResultSet ctlgs = dbmd.getCatalogs();
            while (ctlgs.next()) {
                String text = "";
                String db = ctlgs.getString(1);
                DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection(db);
                ResultSet rs = dbc.SelectTable();
                while (rs.next()) {

                    String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                    text += tableName + ",";
                }



    %>
    <!--Scripts that define the tree. DO NOT REMOVE.           -->
    <input type="hidden" name="value1" id="hiddenvalue1" value=>
    <input type="hidden" name="value" id="hiddenvalue" value=<%=ctlgs.getString(1)%>>
    <SCRIPT src="demoFramesetNodes.js"></SCRIPT> 


    <%
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
    }%>

    <!-- Build the browser's objects and display default view  -->
    <!-- of the tree.                                          -->
    <SCRIPT>initializeDocument()</SCRIPT>
    <NOSCRIPT>
    A tree for site navigation will open here if you enable JavaScript in your browser.
    </NOSCRIPT>

  </BODY>

    </HTML>
```

DemoFramesetNodes.js

```
    var str=document.getElementById("hiddenvalue") .value
   var str1=document.getElementById("hiddenvalue1") .value
   alert (str);
 var table=str1 .split(",");

 USETEXTLINKS = 1

 // Configures whether the tree is fully open upgmon loading of the page, or  whether
// only the root node is visible.
 STARTALLOPEN = 0

 // Specify if the images are in a subdirectory;
  ICONPATH = ''


 foldersTree = gFld("<i>Treeview Demo</i>", "demoFramesetRightFrame.html")
 foldersTree.treeID = "Frameset"

  aux1 = insFld(foldersTree, gFld("New", "Databases.jsp"))

  aux2 = insFld(foldersTree, gFld(str, "http://www.treeview.net/treemenu/demopics/beenthere_america.gif"))
   insDoc(aux2, gLnk("R", "New Table", "CreateTable.jsp?dbname="+str))
     for(var i=0;i<table. length;i++)
    {
     //        alert ('sessionNameVal' + dbname[i]);


      insDoc(aux2, gLnk("R", table[i], "http://www.treeview.net/treemenu/demopics/beenthere_america.gif"))

   }
```

DBConnection.java

```
   /*
    * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
      */

    package querywork;


   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
      import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
     import java.sql.SQLException;
     import java.sql.Statement;
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Date;
     import java.util.Locale;
   import java.util.Random;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
     * @author ash
  */
   public class DBConnection {
Connection conn;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement ps,ps1;
String dbname;
public DBConnection(String dbname){
    try{
        this.dbname=dbname;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+dbname,"root","");
        System.out.println("connected to the DB");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
  }
   public ResultSet SelectTable()
   {


           ResultSet rs1 = null;
    boolean flg=true;

     try{


DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
rs1 = meta.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});




    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs1;
}
 }
```

Comment: I would say that the error is likely to be within the `DBConnection` class.  I don't recognise the name, so I assume it's one of yours - is this correct?  It's difficult for us to help you find any problems with that class if you haven't shared its code with us.

Comment: I have edited the question with my DBConnection.java. But i dont think that problem is with that code.Anyway plz go through that code as well.

Comment: Is your application throwing an exception during one iteration of the `while (ctlgs.next())` loop in your JSP?  Does content get written out in the page after the one database name or does the page end with one table name?  What happens if you replace the contents of the `while (ctlgs.next())` loop in your JSP with a line that just writes out the database name?

Comment: I have getting all the database name and table name in my jsp page properly when i simply display the name inside while(ctlgs.next()) loop.The problem is when these values are passing to the "DemoFramesetNodes.js" file.Inside js file also i have tried to display all the names in an alert box.but it displays "information_schema"(database name) 7(as the loop works 7 times to fetch each db name) times.Hope you understood the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after your comments I'm beginning to think I understand your problem.

Let's take talking to the database out of the picture, as that's not the problem.  Ultimately, your JSP is generating HTML similar to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="value1" id="hiddenvalue1" value=>
<input type="hidden" name="value" id="hiddenvalue" value=information_schema>
<SCRIPT src="demoFramesetNodes.js"></SCRIPT> 
<input type="hidden" name="value1" id="hiddenvalue1" value=>
<input type="hidden" name="value" id="hiddenvalue" value=mysql>
<SCRIPT src="demoFramesetNodes.js"></SCRIPT> 
<input type="hidden" name="value1" id="hiddenvalue1" value=>
<input type="hidden" name="value" id="hiddenvalue" value=user>
<SCRIPT src="demoFramesetNodes.js"></SCRIPT> 
<input type="hidden" name="value1" id="hiddenvalue1" value=>
<input type="hidden" name="value" id="hiddenvalue" value=test>
<SCRIPT src="demoFramesetNodes.js"></SCRIPT>
```

(Database names may vary.)

The problem here is that each time you load `demoFramesetNodes.js`, the browser runs the following line:

```
var str = document.getElementById("hiddenvalue").value
```

In your case you have 7 elements with the ID `hiddenvalue`.  IDs are intended to be unique in an HTML page.  I'm not aware of any JavaScript specification that says what should happen if you call `document.getElementById` with an ID that isn't unique, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is undefined behaviour.   If it were undefined behaviour, browsers would be within their rights to return the first element with the given ID, the last such element, an arbitrary one of those elements, or even `null`.  In your case, it looks like your browser is returning the first element.  Hence you get `information_schema` alerted seven times.

One way to get around this problem is to write out assignments to `str` and `str1` in the JSP, instead of putting them in hidden form inputs and reading them out at the start of `demoFramesetNodes.js`.  So, instead of the `<input type="hidden" ...>` lines, your JSP would contain the following:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var str = "<%= ctlgs.getString(1) %>";
var str1 = "<%= text %>";
</SCRIPT>
```

(You would also have to remove the assignments to `str` and `str1` from `demoFramesetNodes.js`.)

Taking a closer look at `demoFramesetNodes.js`, there's some stuff in that script should be done only once, such as declaring the constants and creating the top-level node of the tree, and other stuff should be done once per second-level (i.e. database) node.  I'd recommend:

- moving the stuff that needs to be done once per second-level node into a function,
- calling the function within the `while` loop instead of assigning to `str` and `str1` each time,
- loading `demoFramesetNodes.js` only once, in the `HEAD` element.

I'll leave this to you as an exercise.

---

The names of your databases and tables might only contain letters, numbers and underscores, so you would be okay just writing their names straight out into a JavaScript string, as above.  However, more generally this is not a safe thing to do at all.  Suppose, for example, someone had managed to create a table or database with a name such as

```
x";document.location='http://www.evil.com/';//
```

This would cause output such as

```
var str = "x";document.location='http://www.evil.com/';//";
```

which would cause the browser to navigate to `www.evil.com`.

Clearly this is undesirable, and is a case of a security exploit known as Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).  This security issue could be avoided by [escaping the value before writing it into JavaScript](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values).